# How do I delete music thats not downloaded?

Tags: music

How come when I deleted all my music off of my phone, there is still music on it that just isn't downloaded? And how can I delete that music?

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes, when viewing the Album or Artist, click on the ... to the right of it and then click Remove From My Music.